# default.aspx is in a subfolder, use it as startpage on www.mysite.com

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a problem. The structure for my website looks something like this.

```
root
web.config
root|aspx|anonymous|default.aspx
root|aspx|members|members.aspx
root|images|.png
root|includes|css
```

I really dont know if this is the best way to organize.. But since i use roles and the membership provider i want to keep control of the users.

Now to the problem, adress to my website is www.mysite.com and if i put the "default.aspx" directly in the root folder everything works fine.
But as it is now the users has to enter www.mysite.com/aspx/anonymous/default.aspx to access the startpage. This is logical since it is where my "default.aspx" is located. But i want to know if i can somehow redirect users comming to www.mysite.com to the real "startpage" www.mysite.com.. And yes default.aspx is SET to be startpage in my VS project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a default.aspx in the root folder and do a Response.Redirect("/aspx/anonymous/default.aspx") in the code

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="/aspx/anonymous/default.aspx" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument

Comment: Thanks, is this way in any point better than adding a new page to the rootmap and use respone.redirect ? I mean in increasing performance etcetera ?

Comment: BY default the runtime would search for this "home" page document recursively, checking each document name specified in IIS; you could remove the ones not needed but I don't see any real difference between this and Summit's solution. Only way to know for sure is to benchmark it yourself :)